# How to store/relate user-specific data (states?) for each model

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, kohana

For instance, if I had a table full of `folders`—with site-wide values for, say, `name` and `created`—and I wanted to allow each user to store their own individual metadata about those `folders` (e.g. `expanded = 1`, or `label_color = 'red'`), how should I organize my database?

Here's a diagram of this example, as I'm currently going about it:

[image: diagram]

Note that this is a similar setup to a pivot table, or a has-many-through, only I'd like to store/access data from the pivot table. **Is this advisable or is there a better way to accomplish this behaviour?**

The reason I think this might not be the most elegant is that it complicates joins in my ORM, because I am joining the metadata when loading the folder rows, so there is a double join when I load that folder as a relation to another model. **How can I avoid this?**

Comment: The way you are doing looks perfect!

Comment: You can store it as serialized string. Its more flexible because your folders can have a lot of params. Create special methods `get_param($field, $default = NULL)` and `set_param($field, $value)` for changing `Model_Folder_Usermeta`.

Answer (score 1):

Your way looks like the best practice. I would put a primary key on both the user_id and folder_id (those two define your unique row) in your folders_usermeta table (although setting a primary key on multiple columns isn't supported by Kohana).

@biakaveron, I would never store serialized data in my database, it's not necessary, you will lose both your semantics and your SQL power. You can find out more on this here:

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back